# how to configure repository for juju?

Tags: juju

I'm a juju newbie.

As known, the juju charm store is the official and default repository for juju deploy. It seems that "cs" denotes the charm store, while "local" denotes the local repository (directory). Are these names is hard-coded in juju?

And, how to establish my own repository server just like charm store? And how to configure it for used by juju?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'cs:' prefix denotes the charm store. Deploying charms from there is [covered in the documentation here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying#deploying-from-the-charm-store)

The local: prefix denotes a local charm. [Deploying local charms is covered here.](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying#deploying-from-a-local-charm)

You may also wish to check out '[Charm tools](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/tools-charm-tools)' which help further manage charms locally.

There is currently no simple way to add your own prefix for a different repository